# Symfony 2 Disallow User Role in Route

Tags: symfony, permissions, routes, roles

So I have a route of

```
    - { path: ^/myroute/, roles: [ROLE_USER]}
```

And I want to disallow it for a user if they also have the role: ROLE_NEW

I tried

```
    - { path: ^/products/, roles: [ROLE_USER, !ROLE_NEW]}
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: In controller `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');` ?

Comment: On each route in the controller?

Answer (score -1):

By checking for what you **don't** want to allow, you can stop them from doing something, instead of allowing it - in other words:

```
if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_NEW')) {
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}
```